# Is it possible to change the 'relative' padding of an element to shift the content?

Tags: html, css

I have an element in my page that I am trying to fit in with the UI scheme we have in place. In doing so, I have a set of buttons that I want to give the illusion of being pressed when clicked on - but applying this to `anchor` elements.

The following image has the CSS padding properties `padding: 5px 15px;` - which is illustrated in the image.

[image: current css properties]

The following image exemplifies the behavior I wish to accomplish. Essentially - to put it shortly, I want to change the padding to `padding: 7px 13px 3px 17px;` - that is, offsetting the content of the element by two pixels right and two pixels down.

[image: second image - with offset content]

This behavior would ideally make it appear as though it is pressed like a regular button element.

Is this even possible? I would rather not move the whole element as one, just the content inside. If it is not possible, I will settle for using transform. I have tried using padding in conjunction with a variance of `%`'s and `em`'s, but the results are usually too drastic. Is it possible to shuffle content around by adjusting the padding of it so that the width/height remain the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this: Changing the padding on :active?

```css
#btn{
  display:block;
  width:60px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#dddddd;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#btn:active{
  padding: 7px 13px 3px 17px;
}
```

```html
<a id="btn">click me</a>
```

Here is a method of achieving this when the size/paddings of the buttons are unknown beforehand:

```css
.btn{
  height:auto;
  background-color:#dddddd;
  cursor:pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.btn:active > .btn-content{
   margin-top:3px;
   margin-left:3px;
   margin-right:-3px;
   margin-bottom:-3px;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" style="width:200px;padding:5px 15px;"><div class="btn-content">click me</div></a>

<a class="btn" style="width:100px;padding:7px 9px;"><div class="btn-content">click me</div></a>

<a class="btn" style="width:150px;padding:10px 7px;"><div class="btn-content">click me</div></a>
```

Comment: Yes, but these are going to have variable paddings.

Comment: This rule essentially needs to be applied across a multitude of varying button sizes, where the movement will essentially occur within the button. I will not necessarily know all the paddings beforehand.

Comment: I updated the answer with another approach for changing button sizes and paddings. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Previously only the child was clickable for this effect. updated the answer to fix that

Comment: you could animate this as well with something like transition: 0.1s margin ease-in-out;